# VBA AutoFilter Runtime Error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

My code is as follows, it throws this error for the last line of statement before End Sub. Can someone advise what the problem may be?

```
    Sub Copy()

    Set target_book = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    last_row_2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row

    For k = 2 To last_row_2
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Range("A" & k & ":Y" & k).Select
        Selection.Copy
        target_book.Select
        last_row = target_book.Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row
        target_book.Range("B" & last_row + 1 & ":Z" & last_row + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next k

    target_book.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A13:Z13").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>", 
    VisibleDropDown:=True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need this line , VisibleDropDown:=True? I never use it. Try target_book.Range("A13:Z13").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>". Also, you could Set target_book = Sheets("Sheet2")

Comment: Is `VisibleDropDown:=True` written alone on the line or it is on the previous one?

Comment: @Vityata I agree, put Option Explicit before sub copy and see if it compiles?